# Why is SQL Inserting the Incorrect Value?

Tags: python, sql, db2

I'm writing a SQL query in Python that inserts new values to the end of a SQL table.

```
month = str(pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.strptime(current_month, "%B").replace(year = current_year)))[:7]

more_orders = int(total.iloc[-1][0] - total.iloc[-1][4] * total.iloc[-1][0])
more_sales = total.iloc[-1][1] - total.iloc[-1][5] * total.iloc[-1][1]

st.write(more_sales)
st.write(more_orders)

insertQuery = "insert into TABLE values ({}, 'First-time', {}, {}, 0.0)".format(month, more_orders, more_sales)
insertStmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(connection, insertQuery)

customer_type = 'Returning'
more_orders = int(total.iloc[-1][0])
more_sales = total.iloc[-1][1]

insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ({}, 'Returning', {}, {}, 0.0)".format(month, more_orders, more_sales)
insertStmt2 = ibm_db.exec_immediate(connection, insertQuery2)
```

`current_month` and `current_year` are user-defined values.

There are two problems with the code that I don't understand.

When month = '2020-08', SQL records it as just '2012'.

Why does this happen? I even printed the value in the variable to make sure that it has '2020'-08'. It does.

Also, SQL inserts these values to the head of the table. I want to insert the values to the end of the table.

I'm using the IBM DB2 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2020-08` isn't a string, it's an arithmetic expression - "two thousand and twenty minus eight", which is 2012.

You could surround this expression with quotes so it's treated as a string, but the proper solution would probably be to use [bind variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054696.html).